# Having a user search and input a file in Java

Tags: java

I am working a side project that involves the user entering a file. I know there is the option for them to enter a string representing the text files name and then have the computer search for it but that would mean the file has to be in a certain location on the computer or the user has to enter the whole pathway to the file.

Is there anything similar to file input tag in HTML5 that prompts a window that allows the user to search through their laptop for the file? I've attached a picture of what I mean would be prompted on a mac.

[image]

Comment: it's called FileChooser: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Or a [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `file chooser` by `swing`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FileChooserTest extends JFrame {
  private JTextField filename = new JTextField(), dir = new JTextField();

  private JButton open = new JButton("Open"), save = new JButton("Save");

  public FileChooserTest() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    open.addActionListener(new OpenL());
    p.add(open);
    save.addActionListener(new SaveL());
    p.add(save);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    dir.setEditable(false);
    filename.setEditable(false);
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    p.add(filename);
    p.add(dir);
    cp.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }

  class OpenL implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
      // Demonstrate "Open" dialog:
      int rVal = c.showOpenDialog(FileChooserTest.this);
      if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filename.setText(c.getSelectedFile().getName());
        dir.setText(c.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
      }
      if (rVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        filename.setText("You pressed cancel");
        dir.setText("");
      }
    }
  }

  class SaveL implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
      // Demonstrate "Save" dialog:
      int rVal = c.showSaveDialog(FileChooserTest.this);
      if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filename.setText(c.getSelectedFile().getName());
        dir.setText(c.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
      }
      if (rVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        filename.setText("You pressed cancel");
        dir.setText("");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    run(new FileChooserTest(), 250, 110);
  }

  public static void run(JFrame frame, int width, int height) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
} ///:~
```

> [File dialog](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm)